# Asterisk AMI - get detailed extension status

Tags: asterisk

I am using AMI from Python. I guess the same can be achieved from the Asterisk CLI. I want to be able to get details about every extension in the PBX. More specifically, for every extension I want to know:

- If the extension is in a call, what is the unique ID of that call, what is the caller id, what phone number was called (incoming line)
- If the extension is ringing, what incoming line is ringing right now.

The system currently has a number of custom contexts that will first hunt and then ring all available extensions and I want to know who and where is ringing and talking. I looked through almost all calls of AMI I could find, but couldn't figure out where to get that information.

Comment: What version of Asterisk are you using?

Comment: We are using 11.4 right now, but we're looking into upgrading to the latest at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digium has somewhat complete documentation for all [AMI Actions](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+AMI+Actions) and [AMI Events](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+AMI+Events) on their wiki. I say "somewhat" because it lists all available actions and events, and how to use them, but some of  it is a little sparse when it comes to the output you should expect to see.

Actions you might find useful:

- [Command](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_Command) - lets you run an arbitrary CLI command from the AMI, useful if there isn't a dedicated AMI action to get information available on the CLI
- [CoreShowChannels](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_CoreShowChannels) - equivalent of CLI `core show channels`, which shows channel names and associated caller-id info
- [ExtensionState](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_ExtensionState) - get the current state of an extension, probably most useful if you have extension hints defined
- [Getvar](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_Getvar) - get the value of a channel variable
- [Status](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_Status) - shows current status info for a channel, including channel variables (which you can then interrogate with **Getvar**)

Events you might find useful:

- [ExtensionStatus](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerEvent_ExtensionStatus) - raised when the status of an extension changes
- [Newchannel](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerEvent_Newchannel) - raised when a new channel is created (e.g. new incoming call)
- [Newstate](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerEvent_Newstate) - raised when a channel's state changes (e.g. existing call transferred and now ringing)

Of the actions, I'd think **Status** will be most useful, and the **Newchannel** and **Newstate** events will tell you when channels are ringing or get answered.